# In a CW complex, what is the closure of a cell $e_{\alpha}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Is the closure of a cell $e_{\alpha}^n$ exactly $\Phi_{\alpha}^n(D_{\alpha}^n)$?I can only show $\Phi_{\alpha}^n(D_{\alpha}^n)\subset\overline{e_{\alpha}^n}$.

Comment: I guess that $D^n_\alpha$ is the closed unit ball in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @Saucy O'Path exactly

Comment: Saucy O'Path I get it,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $D^n_\alpha$ is compact, so $\Phi^n_\alpha(D^n_\alpha)$ is compact and thus $\overline{e^n_\alpha}\subset\Phi^n_\alpha(D^n_\alpha).$  And this is sufficient, since $CW$ complexes are Hausdorff (see Proposition A.3 of Hatcher's book for the details).